# What is stopping the rest of this query?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, meteor

This is probably really obvious.... what do i need to do in the function to ensure this process carries on?

```
function processRow(row){
    console.log(row.title);
    query.resume();
}

console.log("connecting to MySQL")
var connection = Mysql.createConnection({
    host: '178.62.123.210',
    user: 'mongo',
    password: 'xxxxx',
    database: 'd14'
});

connection.connect(function (err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('error connecting: ' + err.stack);
    }
    console.log('connected as id ' + connection.threadId);
});

var query = connection.query('SELECT * from archives limit 50');

query.on('result', function(row) {
    // Pausing the connnection is useful if your processing involves I/O
    connection.pause();

    processRow(row, function() {
        connection.resume();
    });
});
```

It does one record and stops (there are more)

Comment: I should add that "query.resume();" only throws an error.

Comment: Should it be `query.resume()` or `connection.resume()`? You have both in your question, but given the `connection.pause()` earlier, it seems like it should be `connection.resume()`, not `query.resume()`.

Comment: Your error handling in `connection.connect`'s callback is incorrect: If there's an error, you log it, but then you carry on as though you'd connected. You probably want a `return` there.

Comment: Most of this is cut and paste from here https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#streaming-query-rows it is connection.resume() but the function needs a return you think? Just "return"?

Comment: a simple return still doesn't work.

Comment: No, those were unrelated comments. The second one relates to your callback to `connection.connect`, and addresses something which is probably entirely separate from your problem. (It's still a bug, it's just not *this* bug. And note that the `return;` in question is in Felix's examples.)

Comment: There is no `query.resume()` shown in that link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling `query.resume()`. It should be `connection.resume()` (which you're calling elsewhere). Choose the location you want things to resume, and call `connection.resume()` there.

I would look more closely at the examples [listed on the node-mysql page](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#streaming-query-rows). There are several errors in your code where it varies from what the examples are showing, such as `query.resume()` and not returning when an error is encountered in the `connection.connect` callback. Your code also passes a callback to `processRow` which `processRow` never calls.

Here's a version with the more obvious issues fixed:

```
// I would move this down nearer to where it's used
function processRow(row, callback) {                       // <=== accept the callback
    console.log(row.title);
    callback();                                            // <=== call the callback
}

console.log("connecting to MySQL")
var connection = Mysql.createConnection({
    host: '178.62.123.210',
    user: 'mongo',
    password: 'xxxxx',
    database: 'd14'
});

connection.connect(function (err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('error connecting: ' + err.stack);
        return;                                            // <=== return, don't fall through
    }
    console.log('connected as id ' + connection.threadId);
});

// No need for a query variable here
connection.query('SELECT * from archives limit 50')
    .on('result', function(row) {
        connection.pause();

        processRow(row, function() {
            connection.resume();
        });
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

OK, it does need the connection.resume(); My lack of knowledge couldn't work out why there needs to be two.

```
function processRow(row){
    console.log(row.title);
    connection.resume();
}

console.log("connecting to MySQL")
var connection = Mysql.createConnection({
    host: '178.62.123.210',
    user: 'mongo',
    password: 'xxx',
    database: 'd14'
});

connection.connect(function (err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('error connecting: ' + err.stack);
    }
    console.log('connected as id ' + connection.threadId);
});

var query = connection.query('SELECT * from archives limit 50');

query.on('result', function(row) {
    // Pausing the connnection is useful if your processing involves I/O
    connection.pause();

    processRow(row, function() {
        connection.resume();
    });
});
```

Comment: I don't think there *do* need to be two. I'm pretty sure there needs to only be one. But since your `processRow` never calls its callback, the second one never gets called, so doesn't actually cause a problem.

Comment: Note that this answer is just a duplicate of my answer, but with outstanding uncorrected issues.